# R ggplot2 : Getting strange patches when drawing confidence interval ribbons

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to draw a figure with two lines, each with their own confidence interval ribbons using ggplot2. However, while one ribbon draws allright, the other one is all messed up...Could anyone please help?

Here are my data and code:

```r
a <- c(0.009, 0.01, 0.011, 0.012, 0.013, 0.013, 0.014, 0.015, 0.015, 0.017, 0.018,
       0.018, 0.019, 0.019, 0.019, 0.019, 0.02, 0.02, 0.03, 0.03, 0.03, 0.03, 0.03, 
       0.03, 0.04, 0.04, 0.04, 0.037, 0.039, 0.039)

b <- c(0.005, 0.006, 0.007, 0.007, 0.008, 0.008, 0.009, 0.009, 0.01, 0.011, 0.011,
       0.011, 0.012, 0.012, 0.012, 0.013, 0.02, 0.02, 0.02, 0.02, 0.02, 0.02, 0.03, 
       0.03, 0.03, 0.03, 0.03, 0.029, 0.03, 0.03)

c <- c(0.007, 0.008, 0.009, 0.01, 0.011, 0.011, 0.011, 0.012, 0.012, 0.014, 0.015, 
       0.015, 0.015, 0.015, 0.015, 0.016, 0.018, 0.021, 0.023, 0.025, 0.026, 0.028, 
       0.029, 0.03, 0.032, 0.032, 0.033, 0.033, 0.035, 0.035)

t <- c(1, 1.25, 1.5, 1.75, 2, 2.25, 2.5, 2.75, 3, 3.25, 3.5, 3.75, 4, 4.25, 4.5, 
       1, 1.25, 1.5, 1.75, 2, 2.25, 2.5, 2.75, 3, 3.25, 3.5, 3.75, 4, 4.25, 4.5)

Type <- rep(c("A", "B"), each = 15)

data<-data.frame(Type=Type,t=t,a=a,b=b,c=c)

ggplot(data = data, aes(x = t, y = c, linetype = Type)) + 
  geom_line() + 
  geom_ribbon(data = data, aes(ymin = b,ymax = a), alpha = 0.6)
```

Which results in this figure:

[image]

Comment: In your data you have a row like: `B 3.00 0.030 0.030 0.030` - the ribbon has zero width at that point.

Comment: FYI, `data.frame` automatically names columns, you can do `data.frame(Type,t,a,b,c)` rather than `data.frame(Type=Type,t=t,a=a,b=b,c=c)`

Answer (score 2):

I presume this is because some of the values for the upper bound of the interval/ribbon are **not larger** than the corresponding value for the lower bound:

```
r$> all(b < a)                                                                
[1] FALSE
r$> b < a                                                                     
 [1]  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE
[13]  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE
[25]  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE
```

As your interval has zero width in some places

```
data <- transform(data, min = pmin(a,b), max = pmax(a,b))
data <- transform(data, dif = max - min)

r$> data                                                                      
   Type    t     a     b     c   min   max   dif
1     A 1.00 0.009 0.005 0.007 0.005 0.009 0.004
2     A 1.25 0.010 0.006 0.008 0.006 0.010 0.004
3     A 1.50 0.011 0.007 0.009 0.007 0.011 0.004
4     A 1.75 0.012 0.007 0.010 0.007 0.012 0.005
5     A 2.00 0.013 0.008 0.011 0.008 0.013 0.005
6     A 2.25 0.013 0.008 0.011 0.008 0.013 0.005
7     A 2.50 0.014 0.009 0.011 0.009 0.014 0.005
8     A 2.75 0.015 0.009 0.012 0.009 0.015 0.006
9     A 3.00 0.015 0.010 0.012 0.010 0.015 0.005
10    A 3.25 0.017 0.011 0.014 0.011 0.017 0.006
11    A 3.50 0.018 0.011 0.015 0.011 0.018 0.007
12    A 3.75 0.018 0.011 0.015 0.011 0.018 0.007
13    A 4.00 0.019 0.012 0.015 0.012 0.019 0.007
14    A 4.25 0.019 0.012 0.015 0.012 0.019 0.007
15    A 4.50 0.019 0.012 0.015 0.012 0.019 0.007
16    B 1.00 0.019 0.013 0.016 0.013 0.019 0.006
17    B 1.25 0.020 0.020 0.018 0.020 0.020 0.000
18    B 1.50 0.020 0.020 0.021 0.020 0.020 0.000
19    B 1.75 0.030 0.020 0.023 0.020 0.030 0.010
20    B 2.00 0.030 0.020 0.025 0.020 0.030 0.010
21    B 2.25 0.030 0.020 0.026 0.020 0.030 0.010
22    B 2.50 0.030 0.020 0.028 0.020 0.030 0.010
23    B 2.75 0.030 0.030 0.029 0.030 0.030 0.000
24    B 3.00 0.030 0.030 0.030 0.030 0.030 0.000
25    B 3.25 0.040 0.030 0.032 0.030 0.040 0.010
26    B 3.50 0.040 0.030 0.032 0.030 0.040 0.010
27    B 3.75 0.040 0.030 0.033 0.030 0.040 0.010
28    B 4.00 0.037 0.029 0.033 0.029 0.037 0.008
29    B 4.25 0.039 0.030 0.035 0.030 0.039 0.009
30    B 4.50 0.039 0.030 0.035 0.030 0.039 0.009
```

**ggplot** is doing what you asked it to do.

Moreover, you have some values of `c` that are smaller than the supposed lower bound `b`

```
r$> with(data, b < c)                                                         
 [1]  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE
[13]  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE
[25]  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE
```

Answer (score 1):

Your error is because you have some values of `b` are superior to `c` and some values of `a` are inferior to `c`, if you change these values, you will get a nice plot (like for Type == A)

```r
data %>% mutate(testymin = c<a, testmax = c>b)

 Type    t     a     b     c testymin testmax
1     A 1.00 0.009 0.005 0.007     TRUE    TRUE
2     A 1.25 0.010 0.006 0.008     TRUE    TRUE
3     A 1.50 0.011 0.007 0.009     TRUE    TRUE
4     A 1.75 0.012 0.007 0.010     TRUE    TRUE
5     A 2.00 0.013 0.008 0.011     TRUE    TRUE
6     A 2.25 0.013 0.008 0.011     TRUE    TRUE
7     A 2.50 0.014 0.009 0.011     TRUE    TRUE
8     A 2.75 0.015 0.009 0.012     TRUE    TRUE
9     A 3.00 0.015 0.010 0.012     TRUE    TRUE
10    A 3.25 0.017 0.011 0.014     TRUE    TRUE
11    A 3.50 0.018 0.011 0.015     TRUE    TRUE
12    A 3.75 0.018 0.011 0.015     TRUE    TRUE
13    A 4.00 0.019 0.012 0.015     TRUE    TRUE
14    A 4.25 0.019 0.012 0.015     TRUE    TRUE
15    A 4.50 0.019 0.012 0.015     TRUE    TRUE
16    B 1.00 0.019 0.013 0.016     TRUE    TRUE
17    B 1.25 0.020 0.020 0.018     TRUE   FALSE
18    B 1.50 0.020 0.020 0.021    FALSE    TRUE
19    B 1.75 0.030 0.020 0.023     TRUE    TRUE
20    B 2.00 0.030 0.020 0.025     TRUE    TRUE
21    B 2.25 0.030 0.020 0.026     TRUE    TRUE
22    B 2.50 0.030 0.020 0.028     TRUE    TRUE
23    B 2.75 0.030 0.030 0.029     TRUE   FALSE
24    B 3.00 0.030 0.030 0.030    FALSE   FALSE
25    B 3.25 0.040 0.030 0.032     TRUE    TRUE
26    B 3.50 0.040 0.030 0.032     TRUE    TRUE
27    B 3.75 0.040 0.030 0.033     TRUE    TRUE
28    B 4.00 0.037 0.029 0.033     TRUE    TRUE
29    B 4.25 0.039 0.030 0.035     TRUE    TRUE
30    B 4.50 0.039 0.030 0.035     TRUE    TRUE
```

Comment: Many many thanks... Gregor, Reinstate Monica - G. Simpson, and dc37...    silly me :-)